# TomEE Maven Plugin: run using existing installation of TomEE

Tags: maven, apache-tomee

I have downloaded `apache-tomee-8.0.12-plus.tar.gz` and installed it on my computer. However, when I use the TomEE Maven Plugin to run the code in a project for the first time (i.e. using `mvn package tomee:run`), Maven downloads another (embedded?) copy of TomEE to run the code.

### Question

Is there a way to configure Maven to run my code using the TomEE I installed, instead of having Maven download another instance of TomEE?

Answer (score 1):

By default:

- The downloaded (or `~/.m2` cached) artifact is extracted to the `target` folder of the respective project everytime `tomee:run` is invoked.
- Manual changes are overridden as customization can be done via the `configuration` section of the plugin.

Yet, you can change the default behaviour by

- Point `catalinaBase` to an existing TomEE installation
- Setting `overrideOnUnzip` and `skipRootFolderOnUnzip` to `false`, so unzipping does not override things in `catalinaBase`

However, this might not stop the plugin from downloading a TomEE distribution to the local maven repository.